# MySQL getting valid addresses within radius

Tags: mysql, distance

I am looking for a query that is able to take into account the radius limit set by restaurants and only return valid restaurants to the user. This is a little bit more complicated than a typical scenario as the radius distance is usually a static value.

This is the restaurant table that has the radius limits:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.restaurant (
  `restaurant_id` int(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `delivery_radius` int(4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The address table stores the long and lat of the addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.address (
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state_province` varchar(128),
  `zip_post` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(16, 12) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(16, 12) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.country(country_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

These tables allow a user or a restaurant to be assigned to an address

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.user_address (
  `user_address_id` int(16) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `primary_address` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.user(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.address(address_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.restaurant_address (
  `restaurant_address_id` int(16) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `restaurant_id` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.restaurant(restaurant_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.address(address_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I would approach this problem?

Comment: You can use the Haversine formula here, but a geospatial partition might also be worth investing in.

Comment: I had a little look at that. Seems I'll need to do a lot of research.

Comment: This seems like a minor adaptation of the typical scenario

Comment: I can't seem to think of a way of writing this